# Android dynamically change font for ListView rows

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an Android newbie. I'd like to dynamically highlight some rows in my ListView. eg if I'm printing a list of numbers, I'd like to make the rows with a numerical value that meets a certain condition to be in bold.

I'm using a custom adapter. How can I do this?

Comment: You get the rows dinamically?

Comment: @PANDA: yes the row data is dynamic

Comment: and you want to know how to get the data dynamically or how to dynamically change font for existing rows?

Comment: @PANDA: I know how to get the data dynamically, I don't know how to highlight the data I have, to make it stand out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a style in the /res/values folder, for example style.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="textbold" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textstyle">bold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and in your custom listview adapter use setTextAppearance() method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View result = getLayoutInflater().inflate(xml_resource, null);
    TextView tx = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.text-view-id);

    if(condition == true)
    {
        tx.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.your-style-name);
    }
    else
    {
        //something else
    }
    ........
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me get started.

Answer (score 1):

If i right understand you're question you want to highlight some rows. 
You can do that in several ways.

1) You can make 2 xml files which consists normal data view and highlighted data view. In depending of you're data you can replace xml file for view. Such a

```
getView(...)
{
    if(condition) 
        myView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.normal_data,parent,false);
    else
        myView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.highlighted_data,parent,false);

    //do something with row

    return myView;
}
```

2) All steps above. BUT! This steps you can make in 1 file if this applies only font.